# I know a commit ID in a repo, how can I know which git project it belongs to?

Tags: git, commit, repo

I used `repo forall -c 'git log --since=xxx'` to find the latest commits. I know the commit id but I don't know which git project it belongs to. How can I get the project name of a given commit? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "project"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
repo forall -cp 'git log --since=xxx'
```

`-p`: show project headers before output of the specified command

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the remote using:

```
git remote -v
```

and parse the result to get the project name.
The name is the last value of the result url

[image]